# Add mouse event listener on timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm trying to add an `EventListener` to my button which is a child of another `MovieClip` but I receive the below error. The code is placed inside my timeline.

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at Exotic_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

```
movClip.Play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playfunc);
//movClip.Play_btn.visible = false;// this give the same result
function playfunc(evt:MouseEvent){
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
}
```

Comment: Is `movClip` placed on stage at frame1?

Comment: either movClip or Play_btn is `null`, most likely because you either are running the code above on a frame where they aren't loaded yet, or are running the code above in the wrong scope.

Comment: Yes, movClip is placed on stag at frame 1. :-|

Comment: Try to get the `Play_btn` with `getChild` instead the *dot*.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am totally new in as3. If you want, can you post a little code? and can you explain how getChild work?(sorry my english is bad).

Comment: http://www.girlshare.ro/32571081.4 -> if you wanna see I made a print screen...

Comment: I can't see your print screen.You can upload it to your original post. Is `Play_btn` a `MovieClip`?

Comment: I can't..:( i need to have reputation 10 and I'm new here like user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Play_btn` is the only child,meaning it's the only thing `movClip` contains you can replace

```
movClip.Play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playfunc);
```

with

```
movClip.getChildAt(0).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playfunc);
```

otherwise try this

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < movClip.numChildren; i++) {
            if (movClip.getChildAt(i) is MovieClip) {
                 if (movClip.getChildAt(i).name == "Play_btn") {
                        movClip.Play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playfunc);
                        trace("Play_btn found");
                        break;
                 }
            }
}

function playfunc(evt:MouseEvent) {
    trace("It works");
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
}
```

#### UPDATE

---

Be sure that you have named you **instance** `Play_btn` or `movClip` and it's not the class name, meaning the name in the library.
Instead of this line

```
movClip.Play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playfunc);
```

use the below

```
movClip.getChildByName("Play_btn").addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playfunc);
```

Comment: ok, this make erorr disapear, but my play btn function doesn't work...do you have any idea?

Comment: the main ideea is that i have to connect preloader with game. And i spent 3 hours with that..:-o Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2465147 I insert a `trace` statement, try to see if you get any messages.

Comment: I put the trace in function, but it doesn't apear on output:-|

Comment: I placed another `trace` statement.

Comment: now when i press play button i have a erorr : ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Scene 2 was not found.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at Exotic_fla::preloader26_2/gotoScene2()... But is interesting that no one trace mesage apear...

Comment: last erorr was by inside movClip ..but this function from timeline for play btn is not working, the trace doesn't show some message..When i press play button , nothing happents..

Comment: Can you help by another way? look, the problem is that I have in timeline a movieClip (movClip) and this mc contains a button (at 262 frame) the point is when i click this button i need to go to another scene ... what is the right sintax? thanks